# Using infinitive in indirekter Fragesatz

Tags: sentence-structure, infinitive

I pasted the following sentence into DeepL:

> Can I ask you how to get to that station?

and it churned out the following translation suggestions:

> Darf ich fragen, wie man zum Bahnhof kommt?
> Darf ich fragen, wie Sie zum Bahnhof kommt?

In both of these, the translator refrains from using infinitive in the dependent clause and instead, as far as I'm concerned, introduces additional subjects "man" and "Sie". Should I take it to mean that it is not grammatically correct to use infinitive in indirekter Fragesätze, and a workaround in the form of an additional subject is the only pertinent option?

Comment: That odd *how to* construction is an English peculiarity. It does not exist in German. Replace it with *how I* and see how German suddenly resembles English.

Comment: @Janka that is the answer, isn't it?

Comment: My answer is not about German though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many tiny issues.

1. English "station" is not always German "Bahnhof".

   A *Bahnhof* is a large building with a waiting hall and counters where you can buy tickets and very often also some stores where you can buy food, drinks and newspapers. But most important: It's only for trains (vehicles running on rails). But the English word "station" can also mean a small bus stop with nothing else but a pole with a sign on it. Later is a *Haltestelle* in German. For both, *Bahnhof* and *Haltestelle,* you can use the German word *Station.* (Note, that the German pronunciation is different from the English.) If you know, that there is a waiting hall, and that it's a train station then "Bahnhof" is preferred. If it's just a tiny bus stop, then use *Haltestelle.* If you're not sure, use *Station*.

   In bigger cities there are often also stations where many bus lines have their final station. Such places are sometimes called *Busbahnhof* although *Bus* (English: bus) and *Bahn* (English: train) in one word is technically a contradiction. But such stations are too big to call them *Haltestelle* as you usually do with each bus stop. But because it's similar to a *Bahnhof* but just for busses instead for trains, we use *Busbahnhof* in such a case.
2. Different usage of pronouns in English and German

   In theory:

   - Can I ask? (without personal pronoun) = Darf ich fragen?
   - Can I ask you? (with personal pronoun) = Darf ich Sie fragen? Darf ich dich fragen?

   But while you prefer the version with pronoun in English, the opposite is true in German. So, this is a better match:

   - Can I ask you <*actual question*>? = Darf ich fragen, <*eigentliche Frage*>?
3. "how to + *infinitive*" is not "wie zu + *Infinitiv*" but "wie man + *Verb in 3. Person singular*"

   This is a typical beginners error:

   > Please show me how to open this box.
   >
   > wrong: Bitte zeige mir, wie zu öffnen diese Schachtel.
   > correct: Bitte zeige mir, wie man diese Schachtel öffnet.

   Also possible and correct, but rarely used by native speakers:

   > Bitte zeige mir, wie diese Schachtel zu öffnen ist.
4. The German word *"man"*

   This is a generalizing pronoun. Generalizing pronouns are similar to personal pronouns and to indefinite pronouns, and sometimes generalizing pronoun are classified as subtypes of these classes, but in modern linguistics generalizing pronouns are treated as a distinct class (not a subclass of other pronoun classes). German has two of them:

   - man (if used in nominative case)

     > Das weiß **man.** (This is known.)
     > **Man** lernt nie aus. (**You** never stop learning.)
   - einen/einem (if used in accusative or dative case)

     > Das raubt **einem** den Verstand. (It takes **your** mind away.)
     > Michael kann **einen** zum Lachen bringen. (Michael can make **one** laugh.)

   English has no distinct generalizing pronouns. What comes closest is the pronoun *one,* but in English language, the pronoun *you* is often preferred, because in English *one* often sounds too formal. So it's hard to translate *man/einen* from German to English, but it's also hard to translate sentences correctly from English to German that would require these generalizing pronouns in the German translation.

   Here is an example:

   > How do you open this box?

   If you want to know how the one specific person you are talking to opens this box, this is in German:

   > Wie öffnen **Sie** diese Schachtel?
   > Wie öffnest **du** diese Schachtel?

   So, you use a personal pronoun, because it refers to a specific person. But when you just want to know how to open the box, regardless of who opens it, then in German a personal pronoun is the wrong choice (while it's the preferred version in English). Then you need a generalizing pronoun:

   > Wie öffnet **man** diese Schachtel?

   When you translate this sentence back into English, you have these possibilities:

   > 1. How to open this box?
   > 2. How does one open this box?
   > 3. How do you open this box?

   #1 uses no pronoun at all. If such a construction is possible, it is often the best choice.
   #2 sounds formal and is rarely used in spoken English.
   #3 is ambiguous. (Does the speaker mean the person they speaks to, or do they mean the general case?)

   Note, that in German you also can use the pronoun *du* in a generalizing manner. This is similar to the English *you,* but in German usually *man* is preferred:

   > Als Politiker musst **du** manchmal auch unliebsame Entscheidungen treffen.
   > Als Politiker muss **man** manchmal auch unliebsame Entscheidungen treffen.
   >
   > As a politician, **you** sometimes have to make unpopular decisions.
   > As a politician, **one** sometimes has to make unpopular decisions.

   But other as usually possible, this generalizing *du* cannot be transformed in the formal form *Sie*. If you do so, you loose any generalizing meaning:

   - clearly generalized:

     > Als Politiker muss **man** manchmal auch unliebsame Entscheidungen treffen.
     > Um die Schachtel zu öffnen, muss **man** diesen Knopf drücken.
   - ambiguous; interpretation depends on context:

     > Als Politiker musst **du** manchmal auch unliebsame Entscheidungen treffen. *(Tendency to generalized interpretation)*
     > Um die Schachtel zu öffnen, musst **du** diesen Knopf drücken. *(Strong tendency to personal interpretation)*
   - clearly personal (not generalized):

     > Als Politiker müssen **Sie** manchmal auch unliebsame Entscheidungen treffen.
     > Um die Schachtel zu öffnen, müssen **Sie** diesen Knopf drücken.

---

All in all, this is the best translation:

> Can I ask you how to get to that station?
>
> Darf ich fragen, wie man zum Bahnhof kommt?
> Darf ich fragen, wie man zur Haltestelle kommt?
> Darf ich fragen, wie man zur Station kommt?

---

This solution is wrong:

> Darf ich fragen, wie Sie zum Bahnhof kommt?

Because this is in English:

> May I ask, how **she** comes to the train station?

Comment: +1, but point 1 is unnecessary and bloats the question.